# Why do we add Resistors on differential op. amp

Tags: operational-amplifier, differential

Why do we use resistors i differential op. amp circuitry where the relation between the resistors is constant?..
Is it only to define the gain, or does it have more to it?

The question is linked to this picture

[image]

it is said that R2/R4 = R1/R3, but why does it has to be like that?

the formula for V_Out is given to be

[image]

Comment: If it's not worth your time to explain, why not leave it open for someone else to answer if they so choose?

Comment: That said, OP should add a schematic and other details. I have an answer locked and loaded, but want to make sure it's relevant.

Comment: i know about the relationship between the resistor has to be even, to minimize the effect of bias current, but wouldn't it just be easier to use an in-amp, instead of an op.amp...

Comment: @JoeBaker  Why not take a crack at answering this question yourself then?  I don't see your attempt at the answer.

Comment: @Joe: Because this question is so badly written it can't be answered without way too many assumptions.  Furthermore, it doesn't deserve any answer.  By closing it, we put the OP on notice that this isn't tolerted here, and keep misguided do-gooders from trying to answer it anyway.

Comment: Agree with @JoeBaker. If you dont want to answer because its riddled with assumptions or its too tedious, dont answer. Easy. If misguided people want to try, let them. People can down vote or up vote their attempt. And the people that are too good for this question, and its answers can go find questions and answers they want to answer or comment on. Easy.

Comment: But, how does one counteract the mis-guided do-badders?  :-)
 [[ Do bader?]].

Comment: User25282 - the final formula you cite is only valid if you assume that the two resistor dividers are of equal divide ratio. Note that your question is still ambiguous. The phrase " ... where the relationship is constant ..." could have several meanings and it is not clear what you mean.

Comment: The phrase "[Dog in the manger](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Dog_in_the_Manger)" comes to mind. Aren't there enough examples of the putative non-misguided non-do-gooders answering a question knowing full well it is about to be closed? In fact, to the extent of actually remarking about the imminent closure in the answer? Double standards much?

Answer (score 4):

The resistor values don't *have* to be the matched. That being said, the formula that defines the gain won't simplify into the expression that was posted in the question.

[image]

If the resistor values are unique, the formula is:

\$ V_{out} = \dfrac{(R_f + R_1)\cdot R_g}{(R_g + R_2)\cdot R_1} \cdot V_2 - \dfrac{R_f}{R_1} \cdot V_1 \$

Keeping the circuit balanced (matched resistor values) improves the CMRR, among other things.

Answer (score 3):

This doesn't directly answer your question, but it does address one of your misconceptions:
`but wouldn't it just be easier to use an in-amp`

How do you think instrumentation amplifiers work? Are you not aware that **they have the exact same differential amplifier you posted inside the chip?**

[image]

[image]

The only real difference is that the resistors in an instrumentation amplifier are part of the IC die, and as such, you cannot change them.